# select higher than textbox and button in chrome

Tags: html, css

On the following browser it works fine:

- Safari
- Internet Explorer

But on Google Chrome, `modeUser` is higher than `tbSearch` and `btnSearch`.

In the code below, you can see that `modeUser` is higher than `tbSearch` and `btnSearch` on Google Chrome. How can I fix it?

---

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}


/*css search*/

.searchBar {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#modeUser {
  padding-right: 6px;
  height: 27px;
}

#btnSearch {
  background-color: #267bcd;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px #267bcd;
}

.btn_w {
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid 1px #bebebe;
  padding: 0 9px;
}

#tbSearch {
  width: 98px;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgaGVpZ2h0PScyNCcgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDI0IDI0JyB3aWR0aD0nMjQnIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2Zyc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXonLz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMCAwaDI0djI0SDB6JyBmaWxsPSdub25lJy8+PC9zdmc+);
}

select,
.msandsafa {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgaGVpZ2h0PScyNCcgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDI0IDI0JyB3aWR0aD0nMjQnIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2Zyc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXonLz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMCAwaDI0djI0SDB6JyBmaWxsPSdub25lJy8+PC9zdmc+);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 44px;
  background-position-y: -1px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 66px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0033)http://gw.hallaencom.com/UI/_EDMS -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false">
  <input style="width:100%" type="text">
  <div>
    <div class="searchBar">
      <select id="modeUser" class="btn_w" name="modeUser">
        <option value="0">이름</option>
        <option value="1">아이디</option>
      </select>
      <input id="tbSearch" name="tbSearch" type="text" class="tb_m btn_w" style="" value="">
      <input type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn_w" value="검색">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you:

Added "display: flex" to ".searchBar" and removed the height property from "#modeUser, .btn_w".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0033)http://gw.hallaencom.com/UI/_EDMS -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <style>
  table tr td{
       border: 1px solid;
  }
  /*css search*/
.searchBar {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#modeUser {
    padding-right: 6px;
}

#btnSearch {
    background-color: #267bcd;
    color: white;
    border: solid 1px #267bcd;
}

.btn_w {
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: solid 1px #bebebe;
    padding: 6px 9px;
    margin: 0 2px;
}

#tbSearch {
    width: 98px;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgaGVpZ2h0PScyNCcgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDI0IDI0JyB3aWR0aD0nMjQnIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2Zyc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXonLz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMCAwaDI0djI0SDB6JyBmaWxsPSdub25lJy8+PC9zdmc+);
}

select, .msandsafa {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgaGVpZ2h0PScyNCcgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDI0IDI0JyB3aWR0aD0nMjQnIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2Zyc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXonLz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMCAwaDI0djI0SDB6JyBmaWxsPSdub25lJy8+PC9zdmc+);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 44px;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    width: 66px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
    <input style="width:100%" type="text">
  <div>
  <div class="searchBar">
                <select id="modeUser" class="btn_w" name="modeUser">
                    <option value="0">이름</option>
                    <option value="1">아이디</option>
                </select>
                <input id="tbSearch" name="tbSearch" type="text" class="tb_m btn_w" style="" value="">
                <input type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn_w" value="검색">
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: relative;` and `top: -1px;` to `inputs` (`#btnSearch,#tbSearch`)

Set it in `@media` **only to chrome** `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)`

**화이팅!**

```css
     table tr td {
       border: 1px solid;
     }

     .searchBar {
       float: right;
       margin-right: 20px;
     }

     #modeUser {
       padding-right: 6px;
       height: 27px;
     }

     #btnSearch {
       background-color: #267bcd;
       color: white;
       border: solid 1px #267bcd;
     }

     .btn_w {
       border-radius: 3px;
       font-size: 12px;
       height: 25px;
       border: solid 1px #bebebe;
       padding: 0 9px;
     }

     @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
       #btnSearch,
       #tbSearch {
         position: relative;
         top: -1px;
       }
     }

     #tbSearch {
       width: 98px;
     }

     select::-ms-expand {
       display: none;
       background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgaGVpZ2h0PScyNCcgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDI0IDI0JyB3aWR0aD0nMjQnIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2Zyc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXonLz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMCAwaDI0djI0SDB6JyBmaWxsPSdub25lJy8+PC9zdmc+);
     }

     select,
     .msandsafa {
       box-shadow: none;
       outline: none;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
       background: transparent;
       background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgaGVpZ2h0PScyNCcgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDI0IDI0JyB3aWR0aD0nMjQnIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2Zyc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXonLz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMCAwaDI0djI0SDB6JyBmaWxsPSdub25lJy8+PC9zdmc+);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position-x: 44px;
       background-position-y: -1px;
       border: solid 1px #ccc;
       width: 66px;
     }
```

```html
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
  <input style="width:100%" type="text">
  <div>
    <div class="searchBar">
      <select id="modeUser" class="btn_w" name="modeUser">
         <option value="0">이름</option>
         <option value="1">아이디</option>
      </select>
      <input id="tbSearch" name="tbSearch" type="text" class="tb_m btn_w" style="" value="">
      <input type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn_w" value="검색">
    </div>
</body>
```